# ResultSet object has no attribute 'find' when running a for loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this simple piece of code for extracting the text from single post in a given Telegram Group website and it works as intended.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

channel = requests.get('https://t.me/s/eldiarioes').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(channel, 'lxml')
tgpost = soup.find('div', class_ ='tgme_widget_message').text
print(tgpost)
```

but when I try to get the content from all the divs "tgme_widget_message" using find_all() and running a for loop I'm getting the error **ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'** and I don't understand why. This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

channel = requests.get('https://t.me/s/eldiarioes').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(channel, 'lxml')
tgpost = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='tgme_widget_message')
for content in tgpost:
    message = tgpost.find('div', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_text').text
    print(message)
```

And this is the error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scrapper.py", line 8, in 
message = tgpost.find_all('div', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_text').text
File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?*

**Any help please?**

Comment: Can you double-check that the error message you're sharing actually goes with the exact code you're sharing (or visa-versa)? is file "tg.py" the code you've shared? Specifically, line 8 of your code snippet says `message = ...`, but the error says `content = ...`.

Comment: Right, I had two versions and I messed it up here, sorry, I'm editing the original post to match the response.

Comment: arkanjie - many thanks for sharing this awesome example.

Comment: They still don't match; `find` vs `find_all`. This probably isn't the problem though, assuming the error messages you're getting are all pretty similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running a loop, but you're still acting on the single external object. Try

```py
channel = requests.get('https://t.me/s/eldiarioes').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(channel, 'lxml')
tgpost = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='tgme_widget_message')
for content in tgpost:
    message = content.find('div', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_text').text
    print(message)
```

or

```py
channel = requests.get('https://t.me/s/eldiarioes').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(channel, 'lxml')
tgpost = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='tgme_widget_message')
message = '\n'.join(content.find('div', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_text').text
                    for content in tgpost)
print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was so obfuscated that could'nt see the error happened in the loop itself. Very much appreciated, mate! :)